# Object of an interface inside if-statement in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, interface

Hello I have a quick question.
Since I'm not too familiar with C++ and I'm looking through some Code right now, I wondered what is happening in a function similar to this one:

```
#include "SomeInterface.h"

class SomeClass {

public:
...

   void SomeFunction(...){

       if (interface) {   //What is asked here exactly?

           /*do something*/

       }

   }

/*...*/
protected:

SomeInterface* interface;
}
```

Since I'm coming from Java I wondered what is asked in the if-brackets.
I'm used to only being able to put a lonely variable name in the if-brackets when the variable is of the type bool. But since here it is a custom interface-type I'm confused.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: @bolov -- you should probably delete your comment, since the question has been edited in a way that makes your point no longer valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `interface` is a pointer, then

```
if (interface)
```

is equivalent to

```
if (interface != nullptr)
```

The pointer is implicitly convertible to `bool` where `nullptr` will be `false` and anything else will be `true`.

Comment: Oh yes I edited it to be a pointer. So it asks if "interface" ispointing to a non-existing object? I hope its okay if I ask another question: If in the constructor the interface pointer is set to = 0  is this the same as a nullpointer? I'm a little confused by the syntax

Comment: `nullptr` is more like the pointer isn't pointing at anything

Comment: no - it asks if 'interface' is not pointing anywhere.  It could have a non null value that points at garbage

Comment: Even though the object is non-existent, `interface` might still not be `NULL` and the `if` will evaluate to `true`.So this is not a check for an existing or not existing object.

Comment: As @GauravSehgal mentioned, this says nothing about the object being pointed to. For example `int* p = new int; delete p;` At this point `p` is not `nullptr`, it is pointing at something, but that something happened to be deleted and is now garbage. This `if` statement would not catch that.